# how to design a form layout in ios 9 using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to design a form layout in ios 9 .
I tried using the UITableViewController Static Cell.[image: this is the first image]

[image: this the second image]

this how i exactly wanted the Layout .

I did this using static cell with multiple section in ui table view controller

but As soon as I attach a class to this UITableViewController the view goes away on run, unable to figure out ,the code of UITableViewController class is the default code generated by the xcode.

should i do any modification in the code of the class

or should i proceed with different approach.

please help.

Code of the Class

```
import UIKit

class BasicTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet var basicTableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 6
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 0
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Need to see some code, cause using table view with static cells is the correct approach

Comment: can u please guide me .

Comment: new to ios app devlopment

Comment: show your code with your table view methods

Comment: its the default code. genrated by the x code just i changed the no of section and added the Uitable view as the outlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this method `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {` entirely, usually only keep this when you are displaying dynamic cells, it tells your table view how many rows to dequeue (present to you)